# Ubuntu Server 12 not spawning a serial ttyS0 when running on Xen

Tags: command-line, xen

I have this problem on more than one host, so the specific hardware is not an issue.

Bare metal Ubuntu 12 is not creating a login process on the only serial port, in the default configuration. The serial port works correctly with the firmware. It works correctly with Grub2. I have even connected the serial line to 2 different external client boxes, so the problem is neither the hardware nor the remote client.

When finally booted, the system fails to create the login process.

```
root@xenpro3:~# ps ax | grep tty

  1229 tty4     Ss+    0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty4

  1233 tty5     Ss+    0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty5

  1239 tty2     Ss+    0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty2

  1241 tty3     Ss+    0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty3

  1245 tty6     Ss+    0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty6

  1403 tty1     Ss+    0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty1

  1996 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto tty

root@xenpro3:~# dmesg | grep tty

[    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-3.2.0-30-generic root=/dev/mapper/xenpro3-root ro console=ttyS0,115200n8

[    0.000000] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-3.2.0-30-generic root=/dev/mapper/xenpro3-root ro console=ttyS0,115200n8

[    0.000000] console [ttyS0] enabled

[    2.160986] serial8250: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4) is a 16550A

[    2.203396] serial8250: ttyS1 at I/O 0x2f8 (irq = 3) is a 16550A

[    2.263296] 00:08: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4) is a 16550A

[    2.323102] 00:09: ttyS1 at I/O 0x2f8 (irq = 3) is a 16550A

root@xenpro3:~# uname -a

Linux xenpro3 3.2.0-30-generic #48-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 24 16:52:48 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

root@xenpro3:~#
```

I have tried putting a ttyS0.conf file in /etc/initab, which solves the problem bare metal but I still cannot get the serial port to work when booting Ubuntu on top of Xen, as domain 0. My serial line output looks like this, when booting Xen

```
/dev/ttyS0 at 0x03f8 (irq = 4) is a 16550A

 * Exporting directories for NFS kernel daemon...                        [ OK ] 

 * Starting NFS kernel daemon                                            [ OK ] 
SSL tunnels disabled, see /etc/default/stunnel4

[   18.654627] XENBUS: Unable to read cpu state

[   18.659631] XENBUS: Unable to read cpu state

[   18.664398] XENBUS: Unable to read cpu state

[   18.669248] XENBUS: Unable to read cpu state

 * Starting Xen daemons 
                                                 [ OK ] 
mountall: Disconnected from Plymouth
```

At this point, the serial line is no longer connected to a process. Xen itself is running just fine. Dmesg gives me a long list of

```
[  120.236841] init: ttyS0 main process ended, respawning

[  120.239717] ttyS0: LSR safety check engaged!

[  130.240265] init: ttyS0 main process (1631) terminated with status 1

[  130.240294] init: ttyS0 main process ended, respawning

[  130.242970] ttyS0: LSR safety check engaged!
```

which is no surprise because I see

```
root@xenpro3:~# ls -l /dev/ttyS?

crw-rw---- 1 root tty     4, 64 Nov  7 14:04 /dev/ttyS0

crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 65 Nov  7 14:04 /dev/ttyS1

crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 66 Nov  7 14:04 /dev/ttyS2

crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 67 Nov  7 14:04 /dev/ttyS3

crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 68 Nov  7 14:04 /dev/ttyS4

crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 69 Nov  7 14:04 /dev/ttyS5

crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 70 Nov  7 14:04 /dev/ttyS6

crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 71 Nov  7 14:04 /dev/ttyS7

crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 72 Nov  7 14:04 /dev/ttyS8

crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 73 Nov  7 14:04 /dev/ttyS9
```

If I manually change the group of `/dev/ttyS0` to `dialout`, it gets changed back. I have made no changes to the default udev rules, so I cannot see where this problem is coming from.

Sincerely,

Segfaultreloaded

Answer (score 5):

The answer to this problem is to provide an "entry" in `/etc/init` for the Xen required `/dev/hvc0` serial console.

How to do this?

Either as root or using sudo commands, open a terminal and change to the /etc/init directory. Copy the file for tty1, that is `/etc/init/tty1.conf` to `/etc/init/hvc0.conf`. Then edit the new `hvc0` file in your favorite text editor, replacing all occurrences of `tty1` with `hvc0`. The next time you boot using Xen, your serial terminal should now work correctly. You should be able to log in to `dom0` and use the command line, or by hitting `Ctrl-a` 3 times, switch to direct serial communication with the hypervisor.

Sincerely,

Segfaultreloaded

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem.  In my case, removing ttyS0.conf from /etc/init/ and rebooting fixed the problem for me.

I use a bunch of different ubuntu VM images that others have provided.  On all of my other VMs, the ttyS0.conf was not present.  I'm not sure how it got put there on my "problem" VM